# Access files from /home/user/html folder rather then /var/www/html folder by creating softlinks in /var/www/html folder

Tags: php, html, apache

The following is the o/p of my `/var/www/html` directory

```
[nilesh@NileshDBl ~]$ ls -lh /var/www/html/
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x.  7 nilesh nilesh 4.0K Aug  2 13:46 demos
drwxrwxr-x.  6 nilesh nilesh 4.0K Jul 24 22:49 examples
drwxrwxr-x.  2 nilesh nilesh   55 Jul  7  2014 html5
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 nilesh nilesh   35 Jul 25 20:15 php-chunked-xhtml -> /home/nilesh/html/php-chunked-xhtml
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 nilesh nilesh   30 Jul 20 20:41 phpdocs -> /usr/share/doc/php-tcpdf-6.2.8
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 nilesh nilesh   23 Jul 25 20:16 tikon -> /home/nilesh/html/tikon
```

Here I have created shortcut for php-chunked-xhtml, phpdocs and tikon, now I can access (through apache web server) the files from phpdocs directory, but when trying to access tikon folders I get error

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /tikon on this server.

The same is the case with php-chunked-xhtml folder (i.e. with all the folders, which I am trying to use from /home/nilesh/html folder)

I have tried troubleshooting by change the ownership of files and folders to appache, root and to local user, even I have turned of SELINUX, changed the security context (chcon) of the files and folder, but to no benefit.
So, what should be done

I am on a Centos 7 system with apache2 installed